# Make Apache work on a custom port using iptables only

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables, virtualhost, port

My Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) is running on port 80.
I'm trying to make it listen on port 999 as well, but without making any changes to the apache config, only using iptables.

I've added this to the iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 999 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80
```

I'm partially successful. When accessing http://domain:999/ the server returns a website, however it loads the default vhost page instead of the vhost I'm requesting.

Comment: Your vhosts file is only going to listen to the ports you have specified - usually explicitly set to 80, otherwise you will get the default server's pages.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible to achieve without changing apache config.

What you are doing is, forwarding request on a custom port (999) to apache that is running on port 80. But as you have noted already, iptables is anaware of the virtual site and is forwarding the request to apache, and apache is returning the default site. If you have only one virtual site, you can set it up as default site and it should work, but for multiple [Name-Based Virtual hosting](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/name-based.html) it won't. Why?

> With name-based virtual hosting, the server relies on the client to
>   report the hostname as part of the HTTP headers. Using this technique,
>   many different hosts can share the same IP address.

You will need to do something like this: [Running different sites on different ports](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html#port), for what you are trying.